# Cannot launch .jnlp file in precise pangolin

Tags: java, matlab, icedtea

I'm trying to install Matlab but I can't open the download_agent installed from mathworks.  It's an jnlp file, but if I use open with -> IcedTea in nautilus nothing happens, and when I try

```
javaws download_agent
```

or

```
javaws download_agent.jnlp
```

I get the message

```
/usr/bin/javaws: line 66: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java: No such 
file or directory
```

When trying

```
sudo apt-get install icedtea-netx
```

It says

```
icedtea-netx is already the newest version.
```

I'm running the jdk from Oracle but tried switching to openjdk using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

But it still won't work...always get the message

```
/usr/bin/javaws: line 66: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java: No such 
file or directory
```

Any suggestions?  And many thanks!

Comment: Btw, in the terminal using `ls -l` and `-al` I can't view the file extension .jnlp of the download_agent file...the extension I discovered because nautilus denoted it an .jnlp file, but using

    `file download_agent` 

in the terminal gives me 

    `download_agent: XML document text`

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
# update-alternatives --config javaws
There are 2 choices for the alternative javaws (providing /usr/bin/javaws).

Selection Path Priority Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws 1061 auto mode
  1 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws 1061 manual mode
* 2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws 1060 manual mode

Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 2
```

Unfortunately not my brains, but copied from here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/icedtea-web/+bug/969520

Answer (score 0):

Wrong path in my case, when I attempt run IcedTea Web control panel (14.04.1) police
Ok, is simple:
1. open sudo nautilus
2. go to /usr/bih/ find itweb-settings
3. right mouse click and opet in gedit itweb-settings

The making first three lines in itweb-settings, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
#JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java
```

SAVE it itweb-settings.
Open terminal and execute:
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ itweb-settings + ENTER
Java control panel show up :-)